# Using Anaconda in R with spacyR?

Tags: python, r, anaconda, spacy, anaconda3

I have a deceptively simple question that I have nonetheless been unable to solve for two (!) weeks. Any help is greatly appreciated.

I am trying to use the spacyR package with R in Windows 10. I *have* installed Anaconda, and I can locate the "anaconda3" file in my file directory, but I am unable to locate it in R. When I use the following code in R

```
spacy_install()
```

R returns the error,

```
Error: Conda installation failed (no conda binary found)
Install Anaconda 3.x for Windows (https://www.anaconda.com/download/#windows) before installing spaCy.
```

Following advice from another online source, I attempted to install the RStudio integration via Anaconda Navigator. However, I obtain the following error:

[image: Python frozen solve error]

The frozen solve never resolves. I am not sure how to proceed.

I would appreciate any advice you may be able to offer regarding how I can best go about recognizing Anaconda in R on a Windows computer and install spacyR. Thanks!

Comment: `reticulate::py_config()` is your friend. Use this to  see your current python configuration. You can then use `reticulate::use_python()` to specify which python binary you wish to use for the session. You can also specify the path to your conda binary via the "conda" argument to the `spacy_install()` function. See also: https://github.com/quanteda/spacyr/issues/178 for further details.